# MS Teams Bot Login Issue: Successful Authentication but 'Unable to reach app' Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm working on a Microsoft Teams Bot and encountering an issue. Even though the login is successful, I keep seeing the error message "Unable to reach app. Please try again."

When I use Node.js with the Microsoft Bot Framework to display the OAuthPrompt, the Authentication Sign In is correctly displayed. The login process does succeed and returns the correct token. However, an error message is displayed on the Login card itself, stating "Unable to reach app. Please try again."
[image]

**Configuration Steps Taken:**

1. I set up the App Registration.
2. In the Azure AD's Manage section, I configured the following:

- Authentication
- Certificates & secrets
- API permissions

3. I also configured the Azure bot, particularly the OAuth Connection Settings. Testing the connection was successful and returned a token.
4. I then created an app in the Microsoft Teams App using the Developer Portal. I added the basic configuration, app features (bot), single sign-in, and domain section.

**Issue:**
After publishing and testing, the sign-in bot appears as expected. However, when I click on it, I encounter the "Unable to reach app" error. This issue is exclusive to the Teams app. When testing with the bot emulator and Azure bot (test in web chat), everything works correctly. Additionally, when I tried the Teams app in a browser and inspected the network tab, it threw a 502 bad gateway error.

[image]

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insights into resolving this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to a 10 or 15 second timeout that can occur if the bot does not complete the operation. This is documented in the [Azure Service Bot documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0):

> If the bot does not complete the operation within 10 to 15 seconds,
> depending on the channel, the Azure Bot Service will timeout and
> report back to the client a 504:GatewayTimeout, as described in How
> bots work.

If this is due to a delay, you need to make sure your app can [handle the long-running operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

There is also a known issue with the certain versions of the bot builder framework that can cause the body to be set to null. In this [related thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/925300/unable-to-reach-app-error-with-successful-login-fo?page=2#answers), there is a workaround provided to prevent setting body=null by preventing setting None as null.

```html
# Listen for incoming requests on /api/messages  
async def messages(req: Request) -> Response:  
    # Main bot message handler.  
    if "application/json" in req.headers["Content-Type"]:  
        body = await req.json()  
    else:  
        return Response(status=415)  
  
    activity = Activity().deserialize(body)  
    auth_header = req.headers["Authorization"] if "Authorization" in req.headers else ""  
  
    response = await ADAPTER.process_activity(activity, auth_header, BOT.on_turn)  
    if response:  
        # prevent sending None body as 'null'  
        if response.body is None:  
            args = {'status': response.status}  
        else:  
            args = {'data': response.body, 'status': response.status}  
  
        return json_response(**args)  
    return Response(status=201)
```

Related issues:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/getting-quot-unable-to-reach-app-please-try-again-quot-while/m-p/1584462

[MS Teams Chat Bot - Unable to reach app. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419805/ms-teams-chat-bot-unable-to-reach-app-please-try-again)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/925300/unable-to-reach-app-error-with-successful-login-fo?page=2#answers

[MS Teams Chat Bot - Unable to reach app. Please try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66419805/ms-teams-chat-bot-unable-to-reach-app-please-try-again)